# Как передать zip архив на FTP через Swift

Tags: swift, macos, ftp, upload

как можно отправить зип архив через язык Swift. Мое приложение должно выгружать зип архивы на фтп(сайт). Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982572/how-can-upload-a-zip-file-into-ftp-server-using-swift-3-and-ios-10

Comment: да, наверное уж лучше  let-ы, чем аргументы разделенные двоеточием